# Improving the pix2pix Architecture for Sketch to Image Translation on a Dataset of Sketches of People to Photos of People

Tags: keras, tensorflow, gan, image

For a university project, I need to create a neural network that translates sketches of people into images.
In order to implement such a neural network, I decided to implement a pix2pix GAN architecture.
The neural network is trained and evaluated on a modified version of the [CUFS dataset](http://mmlab.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/archive/facesketch.html) provided by my professors.

While the neural network is able to perform image translations, as shown in the image pair below, I wonder if there are ways to improve the quality of the results?
In particular, I was wondering if there are ways to make the image look sharper?

[image: Sample sketch to image translation]

I am already augmenting the relatively small training dataset of 70 sketch-photo pairs to 770 ones.
Furthermore, I tried to decrease the value of the $\lambda$ parameter.
Regarding the epoch, I figured out that the validation loss does not drop significantly after 160 iterations anymore.

[I implemented the network in a Jupyter notebook hosted on Google Colab.](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1f7Uzs7ag4OIC678a2lXN5QDYG0yygWYT?usp=sharing)
As you can see in the notebook's last call, the currently achieved L1 loss on the testing dataset is about 0.191 on average.
[Here is a link to the dataset used for training and testing.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18FrtUqott_RnXloDEneT9ICgAUJGVK92/view?usp=sharing)

Please feel free to take a look at the code and tell me ways on how to improve the code.
In addition, I would be most grateful if you could provide additional ways on how to improve the generated image quality.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to obtain better results with less artifacts by implementing the code of the paper ["High-Quality Facial Photo-Sketch Synthesis Using Multi-Adversarial Networks"](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8373815).

I found this code to be quite nice working for my purposes.
If you need, I can also provide a Colab notebook with my ported code.